# PictureBox MouseEnter / MouseLeave Events not Firing

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Create a new form with three picture boxes.  This code is intended to draw a border when the mouse enters the picture box and remove it when it leaves.  It is inconsistent in the results.  Sometimes it draws/removes the border, sometimes it doesn't.  This code is not complex.  Using VS 2012.

```
Private Sub PictureBox_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles PictureBox1.MouseEnter, PictureBox2.MouseEnter, PictureBox3.MouseEnter
    Dim pb As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    pb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
    ' Debug.WriteLine("E " & pb.Name)
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles PictureBox1.MouseLeave, PictureBox2.MouseLeave, PictureBox3.MouseLeave

    Dim pb As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    pb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
    ' Debug.WriteLine("X " & pb.Name)
End Sub
```

Comment: Do your `PictureBox` controls have child controls inside them?

Comment: No they do not.  New form, add three picture boxes and the code above.

Comment: What platform; Winforms, WPF?

Comment: Okay I can reproduce it, although it looks like only `MouseLeave` sometimes does not fire. Strange.

Comment: The platform is Winforms.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin - so it isn't just me?  I have some kludgy workarounds but want to understand why this happens.

Comment: If you uncomment the debug statements you will see that both events seem to get missed sometimes.

Comment: Changing the BorderStyle property has too many side effects, the native window gets destroyed and recreated.  Which makes it forget it had the mouse entered.  You'll need to pick something else to indicate state.  You can easily paint something similar.

Comment: The solution may be paint the borders yourself. That's even better but less convenient.

Comment: @HansPassant - it is the 'sometimes' aspect of this that concerns me.

Comment: I tried this with just one picture box, and by slowly moving the mouse off of the picture box the code also fails.

Comment: If make enter remove the border and leave draw the border that seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I could also reproduce the issue. So, expanding on the comments above about "drawing something else" instead of using the Picturebox's property, let me suggest this quick and dirty approach:

- Use a RectangleShape object, the one provided by the [VisualBasic Powerpack 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb735936.aspx) addon. Simply put one of those in the same form your PictureBox is in, and make it invisible (visible = false).
- The code is also easy:

  ```
  Public Class Form1
      Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
          Me.RectangleShape1.Location = New Point(Me.PictureBox1.Left - 1, Me.PictureBox1.Top - 1)
          Me.RectangleShape1.Size = New Size(Me.PictureBox1.Width + 1, Me.PictureBox1.Height + 1)
      End Sub

      Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseEnter
          Me.RectangleShape1.Visible = True
      End Sub
      Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseLeave
          Me.RectangleShape1.Visible = False
      End Sub
  End Class
  ```

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to want to do it another way because it's a little easy, there are some ways to do with Graphics. The problem is how to do it by toggling the BorderStyle. I've tested with 1 PictureBox and it works great but with 3 PictureBoxes, there is something strange, maybe explained by Hans Passant.

Comment: @KingKing As mentioned in the comments above I know there are workarounds. I wanted to know why.  In the documentation for the BorderStyle there is no mention of any side effects.  Why does it ever work if the events are lost when, "the native window gets destroyed and recreated."

Comment: @KalaNag - if the events are not being fired, which looks like what is happening, then this won't work.

Comment: @dbasnett but the thing is, while I did see missed events using the BorderStyle like you, I didn't have a single missed event using the RectangleShape... not even when moving the mouse a high speeds between 3 PictureBoxes: It _always_ worked for me. The only difference is that if you use 3 PictureBoxes, you need 3 separate event handlers, not a big deal...

Comment: @KalaNag - it actually seems to happen when you move the mouse slowly out of the picture box, more often than at high speed.  As I have said my issue is that it is not consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Need some help from your Form MouseEnter Event ..

```
Dim pb As PictureBox = New PictureBox

Private Sub Form1_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.MouseEnter
   pb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove

   pb = PictureBox1
   pb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed KalaNag idea by putting my picturebox inside a panel and handled the event on the pciturebox by doing like this

```
private void PictureBox_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox control = sender as PictureBox;

        (control.Parent as Panel).Width = 20;
        (control.Parent as Panel).Height = 20;
        (control.Parent as Panel).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;

    }

    private void PictureBox_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox control = sender as PictureBox;

        (control.Parent as Panel).Width = 18;
        (control.Parent as Panel).Height = 18;
        (control.Parent as Panel).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;

    }
```

I changed the control's size because otherwise, the picturebox keeps flickering when the mouse hovers the borders as the cursor is entering and leaving indefinitely since the borders change the size of the control.

Works like a charm !